# Convexity of logistic loss

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

How to prove that logistic loss is a convex function?

$$f(x) = \log(1 + e^{-x})?$$

I tried to derive it using first order conditions, and also took 2nd order derivative, though I do not see neither $f(y) \geq f(x) + f'(x)(y-x)$, nor positive definiteness (aka always positive second derivative in this case).

Comment: To improve future post, you might like to include more detailed working. For example, in this post, you can include your working to find your second derivative and we can try to see what has gone wrong.

Comment: In general, I did the same as you showed, but somehow late at night I mixed the signs and got negative all the time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$f'(x) = \frac{-\exp(-x)}{1+\exp(-x)}=-1+(1+\exp(-x))^{-1}$$

$$f"(x) = -(1+\exp(-x))^{-2}(-\exp(-x))=\frac{\exp(-x)}{(1+\exp(-x))^2} > 0$$

Comment: you forgot the minus signs inside the exponent

Comment: Thanks.  I miss that.

Comment: The second derivative will greater than 0. It cannot equal 0 based on the exp function.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the given function and then take $2$nd order derivative:
$$y=\ln{(1 + e^{-x})}=\ln{\frac{e^x+1}{e^x}}=\ln{(e^x+1)-x}.$$
$$y'=\frac{e^x}{e^x+1}-1,$$
$$y''=\frac{e^x(e^x+1)-e^{2x}}{(e^x+1)^2}=\frac{e^x}{(e^x+1)^2}>0.$$